# Hangman Game Not Reading From File

Tags: java

This program is supposed to pick a random word from a .txt file and have the user try and guess the letters to the word.  It runs, but it always says "letter was not found in word" even when I know it's a letter that all of the words have.  This makes me think that it isn't properly reading my .txt file.

```
package hangman;

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Hangman{



public static void main(String[] args) { 

     ArrayList<String> dictionaryList = new ArrayList<>(); 
     File file = new File("src/hangman.txt"); 
        try { 
         try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
             while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                 String line = scanner.nextLine();
                 dictionaryList.add(line);
             }
         } 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        } 

        /*  
         * Getting the word and hiding it 
         */ 

        Random rng = new Random(); 
        int word = rng.nextInt(dictionaryList.size()); //randomly chooses a word from the text file 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int guessesLeft = 6; // the total amount of guesses the user gets 
        ArrayList<Character> alreadyGuess = new ArrayList<>(); // keep tracks of the user's guesses 
        boolean wordFound = false; // keeps track of when the game will end after the user runs out of guesses 


        String wordSelected = dictionaryList.get(word); //converts the int value of the randomly choose word to a string 
        char[] letters = wordSelected.toCharArray(); // converts the word to a char 
        char[] hideWord = new char[letters.length]; // gets the length of hiding the word 


        // the for loop hides the word by replacing it with '_' 
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) { 
           hideWord[i]='_'; 
        }  

        /*  
         * Starts the hangman game. The while loop will keep running the game. 
         */ 

        while(true){ 

            //for testing purposes they can use the print statement below to replace the other print statement 
            //System.out.print("\n" + wordSelected + "\n" + "Word: "); 
            System.out.print("\n" + "Word: "); 
            for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){ 
                System.out.print(hideWord[i]); 
            } // Display the word 

            // Allows user to input and displays the guesses that are left 
            System.out.print("\n" + "Guesses Left: " + guessesLeft +"\nAlready Guess: " + alreadyGuess + "\nGuess: ");  
            char userInput = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0); // uppercase the String first, and then pick the char 

            // Checks to see if the user already guess the same word 
            for(int i = 0; i < alreadyGuess.size(); i++){ 
                if(userInput==alreadyGuess.get(i)){ 
                    System.out.println("\nYou already guessed this letter. Try Again. ");  
                    break; 
                }  
            } 

            // records the user's guesses 
            if(!(alreadyGuess.contains(userInput))){ 
                alreadyGuess.add(userInput);  
            } 


            // Checks if the user guesses the right letter in the word 
            for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) { 
                if(userInput==letters[i]) { 
                  hideWord[i] = userInput; 
                  wordFound = true; 

                } 
            } 


        // If user guesses the incorrect letter it will display this and lower the amount of guesses 
        if(!wordFound){ 
            System.out.println("\nThe letter was not found in the word. \n"); 
            guessesLeft = 1; 
        } 


        wordFound = false; // resets the wordFound boolean back to false 

        // if user runs out of guesses left, they will lose. 
        if(guessesLeft<=0){ 
            System.out.println("\nYou lose, you hanged the man."); 
            break; 
        } 

        // if user guesses correctly on the word, they win. Uses the array class to compare two char arrays 
        if(Arrays.equals(letters,hideWord)){ 
            System.out.println("\nWord: " + wordSelected); 
            System.out.println("\nCongratulations! You guess the right word and save the man from being hang."); 
            break; 
        } 


} 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You can test your hypothesis by printing out the word it selects.  If the word looks fine, then the problem has nothing to do with reading the text file.  If the word doesn't look right, then either the code that reads the text file or the code that selects one at random is wrong.  But really, you need to work on debugging your own code yourself, rather than throwing a lot of code at us and making us do the work.  This is supposed to be your assignment, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, ever catch and ignore exceptions!  Change the catch clause at the top of the program like this:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so that you will at least have a hint if something bad happened while you were trying to read your word list.

This is such an important lesson it bears repeating, in bold type: **Never, ever, ever catch and ignore exceptions!**